# Copy to clipboard from CollectionViewSource/DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to copy data on click of separate button to clipboard which is being displayed in DataGrid on screen. I found a lots of code on internet but its referencing DataGrid control in viewmodel. I don't want to send control reference to viewmodel as it make code non-unit testable and violate MVVM.

I'm using collectionviewsource to bind data. Is there any way to copy that to clipboard without using DataGrid object?

Please suggest.

```
public void CopyCommand(object sender)
    {
        if (sender == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var grid = sender as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
        if (grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        grid.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;

        grid.SelectAllCells();
        grid.ClipboardCopyMode = System.Windows.Controls.DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        System.Windows.Input.ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, grid);
        grid.UnselectAllCells();
    }
```

Comment: That depends on your code. Please show your ViewModel and/or Model

Comment: I've updated the question with code.Thanks.